# convert existing web application to Facebook Apps / Google Apps

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, opensocial

Is there a way to take a existing web application and make it available as a Facebook application or in Google Marketplace without doing recoding. How much effort would that require (10% or 90% of original effort).
What would be the pre-requisites around that within application.

Answer (score 2):

If your application don't use any sort of authentication, you can just link it on Facebook's dev dashboard (as iframe) and it'll work. My guess is that Facebook won't allow any other kind of authentication besides their own, so if your app uses authentication, then you're going to have to implement Facebook's authentication.
With Google Marketplace you'll need a manifest for your app and also a listing manifest. And the authentication thing also applies, but with Google's.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Unfortunately authentication is a big need.  Is it possible to build a lightweight wrapper Facebook App which caters to the authentication bit but then uses a web services to show the content of the application.

Comment: Also looking from a different angle, if multiple authentication schemes are supported for the same profile, would teh applications work, if authentication against facebook and google has already been setup for same profile.

Comment: That's the thing... i'm not sure if both platforms allow multiple authentication, but i don't believe they do. You should check their terms of service though. :)